# 2007 honda odyssey starts in neutral but not park

Tags: honda, starting, odyssey

I have a 2007 Honda Odyssey that will start in neutral but not park. Any ideas and how would I fix this or what would it cost to fix? Thanks

Answer (score 1):

That the sign of a bad park/neutral switch.Find out where it is on you car and replace it.

Comment: I pretty sure it wouldn't start in either position if the neutral safety switch was out.

Comment: Not true. It's actually a very common failure. The park position contacts have the most wear since they're used 99.0000 % of the time. Starting in neutral but not park is the most common symptom of park/neutral switch failure.